# How do you create a list of data frame that filter from a larger dataset without making specific containers

Tags: r

I am trying to create a series of data frames based on filtering a larger data frame based on dates. I have a list of dates, and I am trying to the larger dataset by each date.

```
    # Finding all the dates in the dataset 
    date <- forcats::fct_count(df$Date)
    date <- date$f %>% as.character.factor(date)

     # Making a list to store data frame 
     filterList <- list()

   # For each date, filter the date from the larger data frame 
   # Store each data frame in a list 

    for(i in 1:length(date))
    {

      filterList[i] <- dplyr::filter(df, df$Date[i] == date[i])
      filterList[i] <- filterList[i] %>% data_frame()

    }

#Sample Data 
#date
#[1] "12/10/2019" "12/11/2019" "12/12/2019"

    #Output
    #filterList
    #[[1]]
    #[[1]][[1]]
    #numeric(0)

    #[[2]]
    #[[2]][[1]]
    #numeric(0)
```

Comment: Do you need to create multiple datasets?  Would a `df %>% group_by(Date)` is enough or `df %>% group_split(Date)`

Answer (score 1):

If we need to create a `list` of 'data.frame', use `group_split`

```
library(dplyr)
lst1 <- df %>%
           group_split(Date)
```

---

In most cases, a `group_by` would work

```
df %>%
    group_by(Date)
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't heard of this function before.